# Hibernate OnetoMany and ManyToOne throw exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, hibernate-mapping

I'm trying to make simple one to many relationship but hibernate is throwing error, no idea what to do.

Class Product:

```
public class Products {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_user"))
    private Users users;

}
```

and Class Users:

```
public class Users {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long Id;


    @OneToMany()
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_product_id"))
    private List<Products> productsList = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

I got error:  Error executing DDL "alter table products drop constraint fk_user" via JDBC Statement

Comment: Are you using in memory database ? If so then there is no database object to remove i.e your Drop statement is executed against empty database. This happens because  Hibernate does not identify whether object exists in database or its new before executing the Drop statement

Comment: `@JoinColumn` on both sides?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example of such relationship :

Drawer class :

```
@OneToMany (mappedBy="drawer", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<Pocket> pockets;
```

Pocket class :

```
@ManyToOne (fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_drawer", nullable = false)
private Drawer drawer;
```

Comment: I did as you said but still not working:     Error executing DDL "alter table products drop constraint FKpu3y14rfrx91joe0s6m004c11" via JDBC Statement

and : PSQLException: ERROR: relation "products" does not exist

Answer (score 1):

Since the foreign key is on the child side (`Products` class), you can drop it on the parent side and reference to child as being the owning side:

```
public class Users {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long Id;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy="users")
    private List<Products> productsList = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

Comment: Its' not working at all I still got this error:
PSQLException: ERROR: relation "products" does not exist
and
 Error executing DDL "alter table products drop constraint fk_user" via JDBC Statement

Comment: @Demon4i how are you creating the schema?

Comment: In application.properties
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/liblary
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop

Comment: @Demon4i can you try with `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create`

Comment: The same result, I used spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update, and it's work. Thank you for help